# Deny Cisco VPN Access to Active Directory Users?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, cisco, cisco-asa

I run Windows 2008 Server, I have Cisco ASAs setup for site-to-site vpns and remote-access vpn.

After researching, i read that you could change dial-in options to allow or disable VPN access for remote users.

however, i tested this on myself and it didn't do anything..

I have AAA servers setup, using the a/d server for authentication on the ASA. 
The connection profiles user the AAA server for authentication & authorization.

i have two AAA server groups, Server-AD users Kerberos for authentication
and Server-AD2008 users LDAP for authorization

both groups include the server win2k8dc1 (my domain controller, a/d, dns, dhcp server)

not sure why this is not working, any help is appreciated

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a008089149d.shtml#configldap